# The term "" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: python, visual-studio, function, visual-studio-code

I'm working on VSCode for the first time, I followed all the installation steps, but every time I launch a program with functions, when I try to execute the function in the console, the answer in the console is always : (not forcibly "notes", here it's the argument of the function called)

```
notes: The term "notes" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the path is correct and try again. At Line:1 character: 13
+ modalite_c2(notes)
+             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (notes:String) [], Com  
   mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbo3.png)

I can't find an answer online so can someone help me to solve this please. Thanks in advance !
Here is the function if you want :

```py
notes = [9, 12, 18, 11]
def modalite_c1(notes):
  resultat = 0
  resultat = (sum(notes) - min(notes)) / 3
  return resultat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong to type the Python code directly in the terminal. You can use the `print()` function in the code and then execute the code, or use the Python interactive terminal to execute part of the code, and then use the output statement output result.

[image]

[image]